# Дополнить функцию другим кодом

Tags: javascript, функции

Я делаю расширение для сайта. На нем есть функция, которую сайт вызывает для обновления списка пользователей (это происходит когда пользователь прокручивает страницу к концу списка либо когда нажимает кнопку внизу страницы). Мое расширение добавляет данные каждому элемента списка, у меня нужно, чтобы мой метод вызывался сразу после родного метода обновления. Как это удобнее сделать?

UPD - Может получить код функции, удалить ее, и создать снова, с другим кодом? Я не знаю, возможно ли это.

Comment: А как реализовано это сейчас?

Comment: @entithat сейчас я просто наколхозил и поставил таймер, который получает информацию и обновляет список. Вносить проверенные элементы в "черный" список, а потом повторно их не модифицировать было слишком проблематично, поэтому я решил обновлять все элементы, но только когда вызывается функция появления новых.

Comment: @Stepan Вы изначальную функцию можете модифицировать ? Если да, то создайте в ней callback и повесьте на него вызов своей функции.

Comment: @Hikikomori что значит "функцию можете модифицировать"? Мое расширение подгружается после полной загрузки страницы. В этом и вопрос, могу модифицировать, или нет?